# Kendo UI DropDown List does not accept JSON data?

Tags: kendo-ui, html-select, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Using Kendo DropdownList for MVC, trying to identify why the DropdownList will not accept this data.

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
         .Name("CompanyList") //The name of the DropDownList is mandatory. It specifies the "id" attribute of the widget.
         .DataTextField("Table")
         .DataValueField("COM_NAME")
         .DataSource(source =>
        {
            source.Custom()   //  Read(read =>
            .Type("json")
            .Transport(transport =>
                {
                    transport.Read("GetallCompanies", "Home");
                })

            .ServerFiltering(true); //If true, the DataSource will not filter the data on the client.
        })
        .SelectedIndex(0) //Select the first item.
```

)

The raw data from the SQL action has this format:

> "{\"Table\":[{\"ORG_ID\":265498,\"COMPORGID\":239597,\"COM_NAME\":\"ABC Rentals            \"},{\"ORG_ID\":164929,\"COMPORGID\":239698,\"COM_NAME\":\"Asbury Machine Shop                          \"}]}"

Have referenced the [Kendo docs](http://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/helpers/dropdownlist/overview) and other SO examples.  Put the JSON into a validator tool, says its correctly formatted.

In the page, the drop down has a left curly brace, { as the top item, and when clicking there are dozens of: Undefined.

The DataTextField was called "Table" because of the "Table" in the JSON array, but it was set to COM_NAME.  The Controller Method,

```
 [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetallCompanies()
    {
        var ddx = CompInfo.GetAllCompanies(); //returns dataset
        string thedata = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ddx);
        return Json(thedata, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: What does `ddx` get from `CompInfo.GetAllCompanies()`?

Comment: Originally it was returning the JSON shown there starting with "Table\",  but per the answer I changed it to take out the SerializeObject, so now it returns a DataSet with a single Table[0] and many rows.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to use `SerializeObject` on `ddx` aswell as the `Json` method before returning to the client. Can you try changing `GetAllCompanies` to:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetallCompanies()
{
    var ddx = CompInfo.GetAllCompanies(); //returns dataset
    //string thedata = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ddx);
    return Json(ddx);
}
```

Summary of the `Json` method:

> Creates a Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.JsonResult object that serializes the specified data object to JSON.

Comment: Yes, changed it so now it will return the Dataset to the Kendo DDL, still nothing shows up, but a new behavior is that clicking on the DDL will cause the controller method to be re-read, it did not do that before. I have a debug breakpoint on the return Json() line, so now its reading as I expect on the click event;  But will not show any data.

Comment: I suspect the `read` may be getting triggered on each click because of the [`serverFiltering`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/editors/combobox/serverfiltering) attribute.

Comment: It seems to read either way.  And still no data appears, is there any way to send debug info to the console about why this control refuses to display the data?  Does it need some function to iterate thru the Rows and build up the list?

Comment: As long as you have correctly assigned your `.DataTextField` and `.DataValueField` and the data is in an acceptable format then there should be no need for manipulation of the data. There's actually a nice Chrome Extension called [Telerik Kendo UI Chrome Inspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/telerik-kendo-ui-chrome-i/npcmgpnfknjmndbbakdhchgibaajnlpe) which you can use to inspect your Kendo controls attributes (datasource included).

Comment: Have used the Inspector tool, have modified and sent in the data in various formats including String or JSON or dataset.  Changed the .DataTextField and .DataValueField and did copy/paste from the array names.  No spelling error.  Inspector shows empty array, data:Array[0] = null. Never shows any data in simple DropDownList.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Server-side: Leave the `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` line commented out.
2. Client-side: Add the following to the DropDownList configuration (e.g. after `.SelectedIndex(0)`):

   `.Schema(schema => schema.Data("Table"))`

Comment: The Json(ddx. won't accept "table" but does see "Tables"  am working with trying this as well as Tables[0].Rows.  Will also try to cast a string with simple dropdownlist data that comes from an example and pass that to see what happens.